# window.open(newURL) and then submit a post request

Tags: javascript

My web application is running in **domain.com/myApp**. I have a code **window.open(domain.com/dashboard)** to pop up a window on click of a button and load a dashboard app running within the same domain.

The landing page of the dashboard app (**domain.com/dashboard**) has a form that I need to submit to get the desired output. Form submission sends a post request to a specific service end point running within the same domain.

I already have the form inputs in myApp. How to bypass the form and directly view the end results with window.open() and sending a post request to an URL?

**MyApp : www.domain.com/myApp**

**dashboard App: www.domain.com/myApp**

**web service: www.domain.com/web_request/list** method = 'post'

**Edited**

```
Request body:
{
   "envelope":{
      "header":{
         "message":{
            "type":"msg_type"
         }
      },
      "queryData":{
         "table":"schema.table.procedure",         
         "page":0,
         "queryDetails":{
            "field":[
               {
                  "name":"source_nm",
                  "value":"SOURCE1"
               },
               {
                  "name":"fund",
                  "value":"FUND1"
               },               
               {
                  "name":"position_type",
                  "value":"T"
               },
               {
                  "name":"expry_dt_from",
                  "value":""
               }              
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form when the page is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const form = document.getElementById('your-form-id');
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: Are you saying I need to create a form "you-form-id" similar to the form in dashboard with same input fields and send a post request once after the window is loaded with new URL?